# Core data problems in iPhone testing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I have an app which I test in my mac and emulator and it rocks. But when I try to test it with an iPhone or another person try to run it. It gets an error in someplace and sends this:

> 2012-06-12 11:27:26.932 CogniviaTaxi2012[23463:707] Valor: Nancy,
>   Meurthe-et-Moselle, France
>
> 2012-06-12 11:27:26.933 CogniviaTaxi2012[23463:707] Valor: 21758
>
> 2012-06-12 11:27:27.097 CogniviaTaxi2012[23463:707] Pays:FR
>
> 2012-06-12 11:27:27.228 CogniviaTaxi2012[23463:707] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

```
DetailTaxi *detailView = [[DetailTaxi alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


NSString *nomville = [[_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"label"];
NSString *idVille = [[_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];

detailView.title = nomville;
detailView.idVille = idVille;

NSLog(@"Valor: %@", nomville);
NSLog(@"Valor: %@", idVille);

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *villesR = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ville"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
[villesR setValue:idVille forKey:@"idV"];
[villesR setValue:nomville forKey:@"nom"];
```

Comment: Usually we get code and no crash logs, you've given us crash logs and no code! To help work out where in your code this is happening, turn on exception breakpoints (add a new breakpoint in the breakpoints navigator, and choose "exceptions"). Then run with the device attached to your mac.

Comment: thats a big problem I think, cause I work in distance. For me there isn't crash or bugs.. But in the area test it crashes. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Try to share some code. Anyway, the error is due to a nil object for a NSArray. Are you sure the object is not nil? Thanks.

Comment: There is some code... When i select something in a tableView... It saves for add it in another table with last searches. But i have no idea where is the mistake

Comment: Have you made changes to your XCDataModel?

Comment: Yes, but when I send the project it has all the new things

Answer (score 0):

At the end.. It was an Image insert in a NSMutableArray. I had the image in the hard disk but not in the project. So when I exported the project the image wasn't there.

Sorry for bothering.